# непонятная ошибка в python

Tags: python

непонятная ошибка в коде на python

ругается на то что в какой то строчке не так указан "WeaponRarity", хотя всё указано правильно.

ошибка появляется через раз.

вот код:

```py
    def meetShop():
        global hp
        global coins
        global damage

        def buy(cost):
            global coins
            if coins >= cost:
                coins -= cost
                printCoins()
                return True
            print(' ')
            print('твоих монет не хватает для покупки. попробуй вернутся позже, когда заработаешь побольше.')
            print(' ')
            return False

        WeaponLvl = r.randint(1, 5)
        WeaponDmg = r.randint(4, 10) * WeaponLvl + damage
        Weapons = ['стальной меч', 'кинжал', 'посох', 'титановый меч', 'топор мясника', 'лук', 'арбалет', 'копье']
        WeaponRarities = ['испорченный', 'обычный', 'редкий', 'мифический', 'легендарный']
        WeaponRarity = WeaponRarities[WeaponLvl]
        WeaponCost = r.randint (5, 18) * WeaponLvl
        Weapon = r.choice(Weapons)

        foutryHpCost = 10
        eightyHpCost = 18
        print (' ')
        print ('вы встретили торговца!')
        print(' ')
        printParameters()

        while hp > 0:
            MeetTor = input ('что будешь делать? (зайти/уйти):').lower()
            if MeetTor == 'зайти':
                print(' ')
                print('1) 40 hp -', foutryHpCost, 'монет')
                print('2) 80 hp -', eightyHpCost, 'монет')
                print('3) {0} {1} - {2} монет.'.format(WeaponRarity, Weapon, WeaponCost))
                print(' ')
    
    
                choice = input('торговец- Здравствуй странник, желаешь что то приобрести?:')
                if choice == '1':
                    if buy(foutryHpCost):
                        hp += 40
                        printHp ()
                        break
                elif choice == '2':
                    if buy(eightyHpCost):
                        hp += 80
                        printHp ()
                        break
                elif choice == '3':
                    if buy(WeaponCost):
                        damage = WeaponDmg
                        printDmg ()
                        break
                else:
                    print(' ')
                    print ('торговец- Прости, такого товара нет, но если появится я обязательно сообщю')
                    print(' ')
                    break
            elif  MeetTor == 'уйти':
                print(' ')
                print ('удачного пути!')
                print(' ')
                break
            else:
                continue
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "игра.py", line 328, in <module>  
gameLoop()  
File "игра.py", line 315, in gameLoop  
meetShop()  
File "игра.py", line 39, in meetShop  
WeaponRarity = WeaponRarities[WeaponLvl]  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно я понял в чем ошибка. В списке индексы идут от 0, а не от 1.
То есть не `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, а `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

А у вас в строчке `WeaponLvl = r.randint(1, 5)` стоит диапазон от 1 до 5. По этому, когда вы получаете значение 5 и происходит исключение `IndexError`, так как элемента по индексу 5 **не существует**. А из-за того что вы генерируете *случайные* числа ошибка происходит через раз.

**Решение:**

```
WeaponLvl = r.randint(0, 4)
```

Comment: тогда урон от оружия будет умножатся на 0, ну естественно если из рандома выпадет 0. есть ли какая нибудь альернатива?

Comment: Хорошей альтернативы нет. Насчет умножения - сделайте так: `WeaponDmg = r.randint(4, 10) * (WeaponLvl + 1) + damag`. Просто прибавьте еденицу. Это будет тоже самое.